# How to find the angles of trapezium $ABCD$ if known $\angle DAC=80^\circ$ and $AD=AB=BC$?

Tags: geometry

> How to find the angles at trapezium $ABCD$ (that is $\angle DAB$, $\angle ABC$, $\angle BCD$ and $\angle CDA$) if known $\angle DAC=80^{\circ}$ and $AD=AB=BC$?

- $AC$ - diagonal;
- $AD$ and $BC$ - sides of the trapezium;
- $AB$ and $DC$ - bases of the trapezium;

There is drawing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

#### Hint:

1) $$AB||CD \Rightarrow \angle BAC= \angle DAC=x$$

2) $$AB=BC \Rightarrow \angle BAC= \angle BCA=x$$

3) $$AD=BC \Rightarrow \angle ADC= \angle DCB=2x$$

4) $$\angle ADC=\angle DAC=180^{\circ}=2x+80^{\circ}+x$$